# Node http request to C# API

Tags: c#, node.js

I am currently developing a template to be used with a C# API. I am trying to use the node module to submit a post request to the API via the http method found here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html. I am using the `http.request(url[, options][, callback])` option.

My code is as follows (note that I purposefully withholding some of the code):

```
options = {
            path: url,
            method: "POST",
            json: objSearch.getSearchJSON(),
            headers:{
                'Authorization':'********',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

client.get(options, (response) => {
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            jsonPageData += chunk;
        });
});
```

The property `jsonPageData.getSearchJSON()` is defined as a class in c#. It utilizes a controller method:

```
[Route("PerformSearch")]
public HttpResponseMessage PerformSearch([FromBody]SearchOptions searchOptions)
```

Why do I get this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I could not find very much documentation on this type of process.

Comment: Can you please post the exception stack trace? Also, an example of JSON and the SearchOptions type would be helpful.

Comment: debug your controller what is there on `searchOptions` object?